# HtmlUnit error - com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.FailingHttpStatusCodeException: 429 Too Many Requests

Tags: java, htmlunit

I am scraping data from a publication website (ResearchGate) using HtmlUnit - Java.
For scraping the data, I am giving URLs from a text file. I have almost 4000 URLs in my text file (all URLs or page has similar pattern, but different data). But when I try to run my logic for all those 4000 URLs, I am getting the error :

```
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.FailingHttpStatusCodeException: 429 Too Many Requests for https://www.researchgate.net/application.RequestQuotaExceeded.html?tk=i1iSnVitFTozE0uu1nlOqH6CgwJA0vikMY_2VFnCBM3JDz4SZrupIy5I4yAT5KBOFAX-LySwTEIR4dak8u0FRHod9caWkRiNZS6RDGKXCY2Gn7kh80q72oaXjk8RWsXqqfcrNa3ULlnSHgQ
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.throwFailingHttpStatusCodeExceptionIfNecessary(WebClient.java:537)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:362)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:434)
    at com.pollak.library.Authenticator.autoLogin(Authenticator.java:70)
    at com.pollak.library.FetchfromPublicationPage.main(FetchfromPublicationPage.java:34)
```

My code is :

```
package com.pollak.library;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlAnchor;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
public class FetchfromPublicationPage {

    public static void main(String a[]) throws Exception {
        String path = "Path to the text file which contains 4000 URLs";
        File file = new File(path);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new java.io.FileReader(file));
        String line = null;

        String baseUrl = "https://www.researchgate.net";
        String login = <login_ID>;
        String password = <password>;

        File facurl = new File("Path to the file in which I want to save scraped information");
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(facurl);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        int neha = 1;


        try {
            WebClient client = Authenticator.autoLogin(baseUrl + "/login", login, password);
            String facultyprofileurl;
            while ((facultyprofileurl = br.readLine()) != null) {

                String info= "", ath = "";
                String arr[] = facultyprofileurl.split(",");

                HtmlPage page = client.getPage(arr[2]);

                if (page.asText().contains("You need to sign in for access to this page")) {
                    throw new Exception(String.format("Error during login on %s , check your credentials", baseUrl));
                }

                List<HtmlElement> items = (List<HtmlElement>) page.getByXPath(
                        "//div[@class='nova-e-text nova-e-text--size-m nova-e-text--family-sans-serif nova-e-text--spacing-xxs nova-e-text--color-grey-700']");

                List<HtmlElement> items2 = (List<HtmlElement>) page.getByXPath(
                        "//div[@class='nova-e-text nova-e-text--size-l nova-e-text--family-sans-serif nova-e-text--spacing-none nova-e-text--color-inherit nova-v-person-list-item__title nova-v-person-list-item__title--clamp-1']");

                String print = "";

                if (items.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println("No items found !");
                } else {
                    for (HtmlElement htmlItem : items) {

                        HtmlElement articleinfo = ((HtmlElement) htmlItem.getFirstByXPath(".//ul"));
                        info += articleinfo.getTextContent().toString()+"**";

                    }
                }

                if (items.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println("No items found !");
                } else {
                    for (HtmlElement htmlItem : items2) {

                        HtmlAnchor authors = ((HtmlAnchor) htmlItem.getFirstByXPath(".//a"));
                        ath +=  authors.getTextContent().toString()+"**";


                    }
                }

                bw.write(neha + "," + info +","+ath);
                bw.newLine();
                neha = neha + 1;

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Can anyone one please guide. How to solve this error.

Comment: 429 Too Many Requests is something the server send back to you maybe because of the number of requests you send in a short time from the same url.

Comment: Number of request from the same URL is a constraint according to the requirement. Can there be any other workout for this situation ?

Answer (score 1):

I fear there is no simple solution for you. You have to dig yourself and figure out what is going on.

Maybe some hints.

At first you have to get familiar with Http and the general way it works. Try to understand that and read about the error code you got.
Next step is to use a web proxy (e.g. Charles) to see what is going on on the wire. Maybe the server sends some additional information (header) that contain a hint about the rules used at the server side to detect this situation.

Next start with a simple program and try to find the amount of requests that forces your problem.

All in all we can't do the analysis work for you. You have to learn about the way http works, you have to understand what http servers are doing and finally you might find a way. But keep in mind that the peoples at the server side seem to block robots like you (for various good reasons). Maybe you will find a solution, but maybe this solution will work only for some time.

Comment: Thanks for the hints !